# Vim make a custom macro or command

Tags: bash, vim, vimrc

Although I have been using Vim for quite some time now, I am still a novice
when it comes to customizing it. I am not sure if what I have in mind can be
done. Here what I would like to do:
When writing a bash script I have a template to comment a function

```
1  #!/bin/bash
2
3  ###########################################################
4  # template
5  # globals:
6  #   none
7  # returns:
8  #   none
9  ###########################################################
10
11
12 my_function () {
13 ...
```

What I am currently doing is to position the cursor at `line 11` and then
issue the command:

```
:3,9y
```

This yanks lines 3 to 9 into the buffer. Then I hit `p` and it pastes the lines after the cursor. I would like to simplify this process. Can I achieve the above behavior by defining something like a macro? Ideally I would define it the `.vimrc` file and not rely on the script to have the template exaclty at lines 3 through 9.

Comment: Have you searched for a vim add-on that will do this? I'm pretty sure there's at least one on vim.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place the text of your banner in a named register:

```
let @c  = "###########################################################\n"
let @c .= "# template\n"
let @c .= "# globals:\n"
let @c .= "#   none\n"
let @c .= "# returns:\n"
let @c .= "#   none\n"
let @c .= "###########################################################"
```

and put it with:

```
"cp
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was hoping/looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*snippets* are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) Vim plugins is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) (inspired by the *TextMate* editor); unfortunately, it's not maintained any more; though there is [a fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate). A modern alternative (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Automated_Text_Insertion).

There are three things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others; third, how easy it is to add new snippets.